# WebScrape All Relevant URLS / Hrefs

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping

My code goes into a webpage where there are 8 dropdowns.

Each of these dropdowns have multiple URLS/hrefs within, that I would like to print.

I noticed all the Href have a similar partial link text, so I wanted to find all of this, and print their URL, which does not work?

```
from selenium import webdriver
import time
driver = webdriver.Chrome()
productlink=[]
driver.get('https://www.aan.com/MSA/Public/Events/Index/34')
page_source = driver.page_source
driver.execute_script("window.scrollTo(0, document.body.scrollHeight);")
time.sleep(3)


element1=driver.find_elements_by_partial_link_text("/MSA/Public/Events") 
for link in element1:
    print(link.get_attribute("href"))
```

Comment: try via xpath like this `element1=driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//a[contains(@href, "/MSA/Public/Events")]')`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
links= [ x.get_attribute("href") for x in driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//table//a[contains(@href,'/MSA/Public/Events')]")]
print(links)
```

You want to get all the href attributes of the a tags inside the table.